# Openness of canonical projection of quotient topological group

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, quotient-group

I'm studying the topological groups, and have difficulties with understanding why for a canonical projection onto quotient $\rho$ for a subgroup $H$ a preimage of image of an open set $U$ $\rho^{-1}(\rho(U))$ is $UH$. All the following reflections seem to be pretty clear

Comment: This follows from the definition of a preimage:  $$\rho^{-1}(Y)=\{x\in G\mid\rho(x)\in Y\},$$ here $G$ is a group, $H<G$, $Y\subset G/H$, $G/H$ is the left cosets of $H$ in $G$, $\rho(x)=xH$.

Comment: @kabenyuk, yes, but a preimage $\rho^{-1}(\rho(U))$ is included in $U$, so I don't understand why it is equal to $UH=\{uh| u \in U, h \in H\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with topology. Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$, one defines $G/H$ to be the set of *left cosets of $H$ in $G$*. A left coset of $H$ in $G$ is a subset of $G$ having the form
$$gH = \{gh \mid h \in H\} \text{ with } g \in G .$$
Thus we have
$$G/H = \{gH \mid  g \in G \}.$$
Changing perspective, we can define an equivalence relation $∼$ on $G$ by $x∼y$ if $x=yh$ for some $h \in H$. The equivalence classes of this equivalence relation are exactly the left cosets of $H$ in $G$, and each element $g \in G$ is contained in the left coset $gH$. Thus the left cosets of $H$ form a partition of $G$.

Let $\rho : G \to G/H$ denote the quotient map $\rho(g) = gH$. Then by definition for all $g \in G$
$$\rho^{-1}(\rho(g)) = gH .$$
This is true for any equivalence relation $\sim$ on an arbitrary set $X$: The quotient map $\rho : X \to X/{\sim}$ given by $\rho(x) = [x]_\sim =$ equivalence class of $x$ with respect to $\sim$ has the property that $\rho^{-1}(\rho(x)) =[x]_\sim$ for all $x \in X$.

We conclude that for all $M \subset G$
$$\rho^{-1}(\rho(M))  = \rho^{-1}(\rho(\bigcup_{m \in M}\{m\})) =\rho^{-1}(\bigcup_{m \in M}\rho(\{m\})) = \bigcup_{m \in M}\rho^{-1}(\rho(\{m\})) = \bigcup_{m \in M}\rho^{-1}(\rho(m)) \\= \bigcup_{m \in M} mH = MH .$$

Comment: Well, the only thing I struggle with is the equality $\rho^{-1}(\rho(g))=gH$. The map $\rho^{-1}$ acts to merely $G$, not the set of left cosets, so the above equality should give $g$? Am I missing something?

Comment: As I said, we can take any set with an equivalence relation. Then the preimage of **an element** $[x]$ of the quotient set (which is an  equivalence class) is precisely **the subset** $[x] \subset X$. And in our case the equivalence class of $g \in G$ is the set $gH$.